# How to load data from firestore in the table form in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I'm using StreamBuilder to get continuous data from firebase and I want it to be displayed in a table from. I have used DataTable with map function biut it's not working. please help. This is my Code.

```
 rows: [
                  snapshot.data!
                      .map<DataCell>((e) => DataRow(cells: [
                            DataCell(Text(data['Name'].toString())),
                            DataCell(Text(data['Number'].toString())),
                          ]))
                     
                ],
```

And I'm getting this error:

> " The method 'map' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot'.
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a > method named 'map'."

Comment: could you please print snapshot.data! to see what is inside it?

Comment: `snapshot.data` is only the query snapshot. To access the data streamed, use (after checking against null): `snapshot.data!.docs.map...`, which will map the documents.